# Windows Phone 7 - Deselecting ListBoxItem in nested ListBoxes

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox with dates.
Each ListBoxItem (date) have another ListBox with that date's events.

When I select an event it gets highlighted (SelectedIndex/SelectedItem) and I navigate to another Pivot. This works fine.

My problem is that every ListBox has it's own SelectedItem. I want to clear the SelectedItem from each ListBox, but I cannot get it to work!

Here's my try:

```
    //Store a reference to the latest selected ListBox
    public ListBox SelectedListBox { get; set; }

    private void SelectionChangedHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lstBox = ((ListBox)sender);

        //This row breaks the SECOND time!!
        var episode = (Episode)lstBox.SelectedItem;   

        episodeShowName.Text = episode.Show; //Do some code
        episodeTitle.Text = episode.Name; //Do some code
        episodeNumber.Text = episode.Number; //Do some code
        episodeSummary.Text = episode.Summary; //Do some code

        resetListBox(lstBox); //Do the reset !

        pivot1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }


    private void resetListBox(ListBox lstBox)
    {
        if (SelectedListBox != null)
            SelectedListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

        //If I remove this line, the code doesn't break anymore
        SelectedListBox = lstBox; //Set the current ListBox as reference
    }
```

**var episode** is null the second time. How come?

Comment: At a quick glance, shouldn't you be resetting the information of the listbox you pass into the resetListBox method? i.e. if(lstBox != null) lstBox.SelectedIndex = -1;`

Comment: Isn't lstBox the ListBox I just selected?

Comment: It is, but why are you resetting SelectedListBox before you've assigned a ListBox to SelectedListBox? I might be missing something in your workflow, so it's not necessarily wrong, but it seems that you're resetting the previously assigned ListBox and not the current one (until the selection is changed again). When you say the code doesn't break anymore, does it work as it should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem!

```
private void resetListBox(ListBox lstBox)
{
    if (SelectedListBox != null)
        SelectedListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;

    //If I remove this line, the code doesn't break anymore
    SelectedListBox = lstBox; //Set the current ListBox as reference
}
```

When I set the previous selected ListBox's **SelectedIndex to -1**, the SelectionChangedHandler event gets triggered again (of course) and screws up ! :D

Easy fix:

```
    private void SelectionChangedHandler(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lstBox = ((ListBox)sender);
        if (lstBox.SelectedIndex < 0)
            return;
```